# Express receives empty FormData in a POST request

Tags: node.js, express, post, fetch, form-data

I am trying to send a POST request to my express.js backend which consists of a file name and a file. My JavaScript front-end looks like the follow

```
const file = fileUpload.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('filename', 'myFile');
formData.append('file', file);
await fetch('http://localhost:8500/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}
```

My express backend looks like

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const formData = req.body;
    console.log(formData);
    console.log(formData.title);
}
```

The result it gives

```
{}
undefined
```

Why am I getting an empty request body?

Comment: Did you use body parsers?

Answer (score 0):

That is because express doesn't know how to parse `multipart/form-data` out of the box. For that to work you need to install multer parser which acts as a middleware in your request and allows you to access your file through `request.body`.

Here is an [article](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) that explains how to do it with different examples and use-cases, I'm sure you'll find the one that is right for you.